# How do I set up an auto-renew in-app purchase on iTune Connect for my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, app-store-connect

I see the following options when I want to set up a new In-App purchase for my app:

> **Consumable** A consumable In-App Purchase must be purchased every time
>   the user downloads it. One-time
>   services, such as fish food in a
>   fishing app, are usually implemented
>   as consumables.
>
> **Non-Consumable** A non-consumable In-App Purchase only needs to be
>   purchased once by the user. Services
>   that do not expire or decrease with
>   use, such as a new race track for a
>   game app, are usually implemented as
>   non-consumables.
>
> **Non-Renewing Subscription** In the past, a non-renewing In-App Purchase
>   subscription has been used for
>   services with a limited duration. An
>   example of this would be a magazine or
>   newspaper that requires users to renew
>   their own subscriptions. Non-renewing
>   subscriptions can still be offered,
>   but auto-renewable subscriptions are
>   now preferred for the following
>   reasons:
>
> When creating an auto-renewable
>   subscription, you can easily set up
>   the various durations that you want to
>   offer. Non-renewing subscriptions do
>   not have this feature, so you must
>   provide the information some other
>   way. As this is often done in the
>   display name, you end up with a
>   separate listing for every possible
>   duration. By contrast, auto-renewable
>   subscriptions allow you to have a
>   single listing where the user simply
>   chooses one of the durations that you
>   offer.
>
> Because a non-renewing subscription
>   requires a user to renew each time,
>   your app must contain code that
>   recognizes when the subscription is
>   due to expire. It must also prompt the
>   user to purchase a new subscription.
>   An auto-renewable subscription
>   eliminates these steps.
>
> As part of iOS, an auto-renewable
>   subscription will automatically be
>   delivered to all devices associated
>   with the user’s Apple ID. To make
>   device-syncing available for a
>   non-renewing subscription, you would
>   have to create your own delivery
>   system.

So how do I set up the auto-renew option that Apple suggests?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Just found out that I had to accept the amendment contract in order for the option to appear.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so that your question doesn't appear under unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that I had to accept the amendment contract in order for the option to appear.